# Reiterative mapping with the previous result

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to reiterate calculation using the previous result via using map function. I have a code work, but looks ugly. If you have insights, so that a code can be written elegantly, please, teach me. Any help will be very appreciable.

The reiterating process is described as you see in the figure below. 
I have put my ugly code and also my trial with map function. I appreciate your help in advance.

[image]

The ugly one

```
import numpy as np
ys=np.array([10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
xs=ys

from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
g = interp1d(xs, ys, fill_value='extrapolate')

x0=ys[0]
s1=-4

def func(x1):
    return -g(x1)/(x0-x1)-s1

from scipy.optimize import fsolve
initial_guess = 5
x1=fsolve(func, initial_guess)[0]
print(x1)

s2=-2

def func(x2):
    return -g(x2)/(x1-x2)-s2

from scipy.optimize import fsolve
initial_guess = 5
x2=fsolve(func, initial_guess)[0]
print(x2)

s3=-0.67

def func(x3):
    return -g(x3)/(x2-x3)-s3

from scipy.optimize import fsolve
initial_guess = 5
x3=fsolve(func, initial_guess)[0]
print(x3)
```

My trial with map function

```
import numpy as np
ys=np.array([10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
xs=ys

from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
g = interp1d(xs, ys, fill_value='extrapolate')

x0=ys[0]
s=[-4,-2,-0.67]

def func(x):
    return -g(x)/(x0-x)-s

xall=list(map(func, s))

from scipy.optimize import fsolve
initial_guess = 5*np.ones(s.size)
xi=fsolve(xall, initial_guess)[0]
print(xi)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to use a `lambda` function as input to `fsolve`. Something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

ys = np.array([10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
xs = ys
g = interp1d(xs, ys, fill_value='extrapolate')

x0 = ys[0]
s = [-4, -2, -0.67]
initial_guess = 5

for si in s:
    x0 = fsolve(lambda x1: -g(x1)/(x0 - x1) - si, initial_guess)[0]
    print(x0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. The code works for me sure. But I wonder, is there anyway, we can do this using map over i-loop? I might be wrong, but I heard map is more efficient way than i-loop. Any comment will be appreciable.

Comment: The problem here is that you need to wait for the previous run of `fsolve` to use its output into the next iteration. So `map` would not work in this case. `map` maps an iterable to a function. So you can map `s` to the approximation function, but the approximation function also needs previous x (`x0`) after each iteration. So you do need a `for` loop for this. If you do not have a lot of iterations (< 1000) probably there is no need to worry about the loop performance, since most of the time would be spent in `fsolve` anyway.

Comment: I see your point. I really appreciate your help and insights. Best,